# Preselect options in select2 from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-select2

As with disabled: true and locked: true is there a way to preselect an option in select2?
I have a text field that gets json data and i want to preselect an option

Is there something like this?

```
{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug', selected: true},{id: 2, text: 'task'}
```

I know it can be done with initSelection but i don't understand how to get selected: true

Can you help please?

Look at the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9PZTm/1/

Answer (score 0):

I found something that worked for me

Here is the code if someone need it:

```
var items = [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug', selected: true},{id: 2, text: 'task'}];
$(".form-control").select2({
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term, selected:term};} },
    multiple: false,
    data: items,
    width: 218,
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        $(items).each(function(){
           if (this.selected != undefined){
                callback(this);
           }
        });
    },
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9PZTm/2/

Answer (score 0):

I used an array instead

```
let arr = ['1','0']; 
$('#multiple').val(arr).select2();
```